# Update table php + MySQL, Как сделать максимально эффективно с точки зрения производительности?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица, которая хранит сведения о товарах вида:

```
CREATE TABLE `products ` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`name` tinytext,
`price` float(9,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
`color` tinytext,
UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=innoDB;
```

Стоит задача, обновить цену в зависимости от цвета товара.

Например, товарам с color=red цену уменьшить на 5%, товарам с color=green, увеличить цену на 10% и т.д.

Как это сделать максимально эффективно с точки зрения производительности?
В стеке PHP + MySQL

Comment: А завтра % будет 5 для green и 10 для red?.. Что мешает при выводе считать цену?

Comment: Да ничто не мешает, а что это даст?

Comment: Гибкость это даст.. Вы либо в отдельной таблице % указывайте, либо в конфиге каком-нибудь и считайте при выводе цену

Comment: Т.е считаете что цену в основной таблице не перезаписывать, а рассчитывать ее при выводе?

Comment: Верно, считаю так лучше

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, если решать проблему "в лоб" - тогда как-нибудь так:

```
UPDATE products SET price = CASE
    WHEN color = 'red' THEN price * 0.95
    WHEN color = 'green' THEN price * 1.10
    ELSE price
END
```

Но вообще, как в комментариях уже отметили, лучше логику подсчёта цены сделать отдельным шагом в программе.